# Cannot access JSON dictionary results

Tags: ios, json, swift3

I am not getting what is wrong here, I am retrieving a JSON through Alamofire:

```
let JSON = response.result.value as! [String : Any]
print("JSON: \(JSON)")
let statusCode = response.response?.statusCode ?? 999
```

which is printing in the console:

```
JSON: ["message": <null>, "value": <__NSArray0 0x174011b30>(

)
, "error": 0]
```

Therefore JSON is set correctly.
I have then set a breakpoint immediately after the print (same scope then) on the statusCode assignment, but when I type in the console po JSON, I get the following error:

(lldb) po JSON
error: :3:1: error: use of unresolved identifier 'JSON'

And consequently all the lines after that are failing:

```
let resultCode = JSON["error"] as! Int
let resultMessage = JSON["message"] as! String
let resultValue = JSON["value"] as! [AnyObject]
```

Can someone figure out why this is happening? This is Swift 3.1 with Xcode 8.3.2

The json is:

```
{
  "error": false,
  "message": null,
  "value": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "deviceId": "E5E3ED6B-8645-4894-8939-DC6AC7B4C37E"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: add your json format also .

Comment: First print: `print(response.result.value ?? "No Value is coming from JSON")` first, if you get values from json then please put your JSON value here.

Comment: Console log is telling you the `"message": <null>`, so your code crashes at `let resultMessage = JSON["message"] as! String` As the value is null and not String.

Comment: That is not the point, I am trying to po the entire JSON immediately after the print is able to print it, and I am getting the error

Comment: @FabrizioProsperi Add more code it looks like you are using JSON some where else not at the place where you are initializing it

Comment: @FabrizioProsperi 1. Make sure you set the breakpoint after JSON is initialised and in the same scope. 2. Make sure `po JSON` is not trying to reference some other type/method, for example by changing the variable name to 'jsonDictionary`.

Comment: NiravD, Pahnev no, I am actually using JSON at proper scope. Vadian response clarified the issue, which was error not Int but Bool. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Two general issues:

- The value for key `error` is `Bool` rather than `Int`.
- The value for key `message` is `NSNull`, it is most likely `String` if `error` is true.

---

I recommend to check for the `error` value:

```
if let JSON = response.result.value as? [String : Any] {
    if let error = JSON["error"] as? Bool, error == true {
       print(JSON["message"])
    } else {
       if let resultArray = JSON["value"] as? [[String:Any]] {
          for result in resultArray {
              print("deviceId: ", result["deviceId"] as? String ?? "n/a")
          }
       }
    }
}
```